# Doubts about a Bug/Error sender via email

Tags: c#, email, authentication

I'm developing a open source project. This project is getting bigger and may fail and crash as normal, so I tought of doing a crash sender to get the errors (if the user wants) via email.

But, since it's a open source project hosted in a easy to access site, I can't just hardcode the login and password of my software's email.

> Do you guys have any better way to send crash reports (without having
>   a proper site, I'm using Codeplex) or a easy way to hide any password?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the email from the client program, create a web service ([WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) or [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)) that it can call to send an email. Your web service will handle generating the email and will contain the login details for the email provider.

If you wanted to take the idea one step further, then your web service can hook into a database where you record various details about the crash (such as Windows Version #, relevant environment variables or registry settings etc). That'd give you an easy way to keep track of your crashes over time.

Comment: The problem is: I don't have a server to host a webservice.

Comment: Get one! You can host up to 10 sites for free with [Azure](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx). The domain will end up being myrandomsite.azurewebsites.net but it doesn't matter since the site isn't meant for people to visit.